# How to read raw http response from ISAPI dll using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, sockets, httpresponse, httpurlconnection, isapi-extension

My requirement is to send and receive HTTP request and response from ISAPI dll which is hosted in IIS using Java. Our ISAPI dll sends raw xml data as response without http headers so when calling `HTTPURLConnection.getinputstream()` from client I am getting `UnknownLengthHttpInputStream` exception.
 Can I use `HTTPURLConnection` to read the http response data without header details or should I use sockets to read response in client?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call [HttpURLConnection.getInputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getInputStream%28%29) and read your xml data from there.

Comment: Since my ISAPI is not sending http response header along with response while calling HTTPURLConnection.getInputStream() I am getting UnknownLengthHttpInputStream  exception.Is it possible to read raw response body using HTTPURLConnection without the header details or should I go for any other approach like socket programming?

Comment: @sujitharam if that's the case, then no, you can't use a HttpURLConnection because you're no longer compliant with the protocol. You'll need to just open a Socket and read from it.